# Read the 1st line of a file without line terminator

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to read the 1st non null line of a .txt file, and store it in a folder who will have as name the 1st valid line of that .txt.

so my C:/Test/new1.txt starts with 2 empty lines followed by :

```
 example
 this is an example
```

and I want to rename/copy it to C:/Test/example.txt

I have this function which go recursively and get me all the .txt file in all folder and subfolders I want. Now I try to read the 1st valid line, and its works too, but when I move/copy it, I always gets an error : illegal characters in path.

I tried to trim the title, to replace vbLf. etc ... to no avail

```
   singleFile = New IO.FileInfo(Fullpath)
   Dim sr As New StreamReader(singleFile.FullName)
   Dim title As String = Trim(sr.ReadLine).Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")
   While title = ""
         title = Trim(sr.ReadLine).Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")
   End While
   filepath = singleFile.Directory.FullName & "\" & title & ".txt"
   FileSystem.CopyFile(singleFile.FullName, filepath)
```

but the streamreader still tries to put a line terminator at the end of the title, how can I get rid of it ?

I always get the illegal char in title error, and my filepath = c:/test/exemple      .txt
(note the space between exemple and .txt)

EDIT :

the problem is not a carriage return, it seems one of the imported file I'm trying to filter have another ascii char as a "line terminator". so my question will probably twist on how to remove all blank or special char from a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer to most similar case would be to use a regex to simply ignore all characters that aren't in the specified range you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fullPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "new1.txt")
        Dim fileText As String = String.Empty
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath) Then
            fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath)
        Else
            Throw New System.IO.FileNotFoundException("The specified file was not found.")
        End If
        Dim newName As String = FirstNonBlankLine(fileText) & ".txt"
        Dim originalPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)
        Dim newPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalPath, newName)
        MsgBox(newPath)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newPath, fileText)
    End Sub
    Function FirstNonBlankLine(fileText As String) As String
        fileText = fileText.Replace(vbLf, vbCr).Replace(vbCr & vbCr, vbCr)
        Dim lines As String() = fileText.Split({vbCr}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Return lines(0)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: nope, test  .txt is what I get ( there might be other garbage in the .txt aside VBLF ... I think this is a tab considering the size, I didnt had that on my tests, so i'll try to mix add a trim on top of your test) ... the files arent created myself they are imported )

Comment: Thanks for that new syntax, but the Trim got rid of the tab, but not the blank space at the end of the title . :/ ...

Comment: Can you upload an unmodified copy of the text file?

Comment: I've done it with a custom regex to get rid of everything that didnt match our needed.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Path As String = "C:/Test/new1.txt"
Dim Str As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(Path).Trim
IO.File.Copy(Path, "C:/Test/" + Split(Str, vbCrLf)(0) + ".txt") 'With Lines
'Or write the file without Lines
'IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/Test/" + Split(Str, vbCrLf)(0) + ".txt", Str)
```

EDIT : 
    Ok, you can check the ASCII value

```
 Dim Path As String = "C:/Test/new1.txt"
    Dim Str As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(Path).Trim
    IO.File.Copy(Path, "C:/Test/" + GetChars(Split(Str, vbCrLf)(0)) + ".txt")



    Function GetChars(Str As String) As String
    Dim Final As String = ""
    Dim NoInPath As String = "/\*:<>?|" + ChrW(34) ' (34=")
    For Each x As Char In Str
        Try
            If Asc(x) >= 32 And Asc(x) <= 126 Then 'English Language
                If NoInPath.Contains(x) = False Then Final += x
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
    Return Final
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the info, didnt help my particular problem, but at least I can keep digging a bit furthur now.